# Crop vectors imported as pixel into layer into Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm trying to achieve the below outcome of a 3 different layers - vectors created in Illustrator. These vectors I imported in Photoshop as pixels and tried to achieve as shown in the picture by using the path tool and then I created a layer mask on that one I wanted to crop.

My problem is that those wavy lines are difficult to create (or I'm not that good enough with Photoshop).

Is there any other better way of doing so?

[image]

Comment: You can use a Clipping Mask in illustrator. Not sure if that makes it any easier for you though.

Comment: I don't understand this question at all. What are you trying to crop? Please realize no one here knows what any original may look like or what your end goal may be. You need to describe things with that in mind.

Comment: Are you saying that you tried to import vectors from Illustrator to Photoshop, and they became raster images instead, forcing you to re-create the mask?